# How can i divide the static media files that react builds in subfolders?

Tags: reactjs, build, static, media, subdirectory

I was trying to use the build/static/media folder for production and i need to divide my pictures in subfolders. Is that possible? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Why is it you want to divide the production assets into subfolders? Understanding why and what exactly you're trying to do may help to come up with the best answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.